# How to make YouTube embedded player start video on certain event

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm using jQuery to try to show a hidden YouTube player, and then start playing the video once its containing div is shown.

The problem is that this only works on Chrome, not in IE or FireFox.  In IE, I see the error:  JSON is undefined.

What can I do to make this work right in all three browsers?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'r3lPq7qY3TU',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
    });

            $('div#target_wrap img, div#main_vid').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var p = $('#player');

                p.slideToggle(function(){
                    if (p.is(":visible")) {
                        player.playVideo();
                    } else {
                        player.stopVideo();
                    }
                });
            });
  }
```

Comment: So, I am amusing the error is not on this part of the code. You have  problem on API JSON callback

Comment: The error does point to YouTube's code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's lucky accident that it works on Chrome in the first place.  For example a common problem is not waiting for the call to "onYouTubePlayerReady".  At least for debugging purposes you'll also want to do something like:

```
$('div#target_wrap img, div#main_vid').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#player').slideToggle(function(){
        if (player.getPlayerState) {
            alert("player state: " + player.getPlayerState());
            if ($('#player').is(":visible")) {
                player.playVideo();
            } else {
                player.stopVideo();
            }
        } else {
            alert("Player not ready yet.");
        }

    });
});
```

If you can share more of your code we might have a better answer.

Comment: So this is the newer iframe API that is still labeled "experimental".  It could be that you're using "display: none" CSS rule to hide the videos in the first place.  I vaguely remember using this at one time and running into problems with the timing of the player initialization.  Nevertheless I still recommend checking the state before trying to play the videos -- at least while debugging.

Comment: I was using display:none.  I wound up having to use the older embed api, though.  Once I developed with the idea that the hidden div was the problem, I was able to figure it out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you can't achieve crossbrowser compatibility i give you a suggestion:

onClick call the same video again but with the parameter &autoplay=1

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know anything about playing YouTube videos via JS, but some versions of IE doesn't include an implementation of the JSON object which serializes/deserializes to/from JSON. You can find an implementation [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json.js).

You may wish to include this via conditional comments or use a script loader so it's loaded only when needed.